# Redshift Json extract path text

Tags: amazon-redshift

Hi I was using this code to extract data from a column it was working, but I am now getting an error message. Any input is appreciated.

### SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: JSON parsing error
Detail:

error:  JSON parsing error
code:      8001
context:   invalid json object false
query:     6047879
location:  funcs_json.hpp:127
process:   query1_117_6047879 [pid=6614]

```
    select json_extract_path_text (info,'device_category')     as device_category
from admin.project
```

Comment: It looks like you are running a json function on a string that isn't valid json.  Can you post the source string (info) that is causing the error?

Comment: Sorry I took long to reply, I figured out the problem. There was issues with the json format in our DW, thank you @BillWeiner